# I want show Progressbar in windows application till Restoring a Database

Tags: c#

```
public void RestoreDatabase(String databaseName, String filePath, String serverName, String userName, String password, String dataFilePath, String logFilePath)
        {
            Restore sqlRestore = new Restore();

            BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(filePath, DeviceType.File);
            sqlRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
            sqlRestore.Database = databaseName;

            ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
            Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

            Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
            sqlRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;

            string dataFileLocation = dataFilePath.ToString().Trim();
            string logFileLocation = logFilePath.ToString().Trim();
            db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
            RelocateFile rf = new RelocateFile(databaseName, dataFileLocation);


            sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(dataFilePath.Substring(dataFilePath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1, dataFilePath.LastIndexOf('.') - 3), dataFileLocation));
            sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(dataFilePath.Substring(dataFilePath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1, dataFilePath.LastIndexOf('.') - 3) + "_log", logFileLocation));
            sqlRestore.NoRecovery = false;
            sqlRestore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
            sqlRestore.Complete += new ServerMessageEventHandler(sqlRestore_Complete);
            sqlRestore.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;
            sqlRestore.PercentComplete +=
               new PercentCompleteEventHandler(sqlRestore_PercentComplete);

            sqlRestore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);

            db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
            db.SetOnline();
            sqlServer.Refresh();          

        }
```

Comment: which application windows or web .. no information available, what is been tried and where issue is being faced also not mentioned ..

Comment: It is windows application. Progressbar value is increasing after completion of Restoring database. I want it increase parallel